# Oscilation Property of absolutely continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

I have a question about absolutely continuous function $f:[0,T]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. First, as we know, as a function with finite variation, $f$ is almost everywhere differentiable. However, I expect a property stronger than that.

We may write : $f(t)=\int_0^t\phi(s) ds$. My question is whether there exists a function $\varphi$ such that
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\int_t^{t+h}|\phi(s) -\varphi(t)|ds}{h}=0,\ t\text{-a.s.}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the  Lebesgue differentiation theorem gives this. Let $\phi\in L^1[0,T]$, meaning we pick a particular function $\phi$ from an equivalence class that is an element of $L^1[0,T]$. Then for a.e. $t\in [0,T]$ we have 
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\int_t^{t+h}|\phi(s) -\phi(t)|\,ds}{h}=0 \tag{1}$$
Indeed, (1) is a trivial consequence of 
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\int_{t-h}^{t+h}|\phi(s) -\phi(t)|\,ds}{2h}=0 \tag{2}$$
which is a more usual form of the Lebesgue differentiation. Or you could prove it directly, decomposing $\phi$ into continuous function + function of small $L^1$ norm, and using the weak $(1,1)$ inequality for maximal function to control the contribution for the latter.